# insert data in dynamic table using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

insert.php

```
<?php
$nidErr = $scodeErr = $constituencyErr = "";
$nid = $scode = $constituency = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["nid"])) {
$nidErr = "*";
} else {
$nid = test_input($_POST["nid"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["scode"])) {
$scodeErr = "*";
} else {
$scode= test_input($_POST["scode"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["constituency"])) {
$constituencyErr = "*";
} else {
$constituency= test_input($_POST["constituency"]);

}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data; }
?>


<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">

<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')">

<table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"></td>
<td>National ID Number<span class="error">* <?php echo $nidErr;?></span>     

<input type="text" name="nid[]"></td>
<td>Security Code <span class="error">* <?php echo $scodeErr;?></span><input  

type="text" name="scode[]"></td>

<td><span class="error">* <?php echo $constituencyErr;?></span>
<select name="constituency[]">
<option value="in">Select Constituency</option>
<option value="de">Mirsorai1</option>
<option value="fr">Comilla1</option>
<option value="us">Dhaka1</option> 
<option value="ch">Sylhet1</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>


<br><input type = "submit" value = "submit">

</form>
```

insert_post.php

```
<?php
if ( $_POST["nid"] && $_POST["scode"] && $_POST["constituency"] ){

include("dbcon.php");

foreach($constituency as $a => $b){
$a+1;
$nid = $_POST['nid'][$a];
$scode = $_POST['scode'][$a];
$constituency = $_POST['constituency'][$a];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO voterlist(constituency,scode,nid)
VALUES ('$constituency', '$scode', '$nid')");
}

}

?>

<table id='display'>

<tr>  
<td><?php echo "National ID:<br>" ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "Security Code:<br>" ; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo "Constituency:<br>" ; ?></td> 



<hr>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><?php echo "<br>" .$nid; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "<br>".$scode; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo "<br>".$constituency; ?></td> 

</tr>


<?php   

?> 
</table>
```

**** I would like to show the data in insert_post.php page. but it showing error also data is not stored in the backend.I am confused about the foreach loop. I would like to have some suggestion regarding this.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and if you get an error, TELL US what it is. Don't make us guess.

Comment: it showing error in foreach loop

Comment: and that error is....? like I said, don't make us GUESS what the errror is.

Comment: It say "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" also " undefined variable"

Comment: so where did you define $constituency? You just start using it... And just because a variable exists in one of your .php files doesn't magically make it appear in all of the other .php files.

Comment: i got ur point. thanks

Comment: I have made some changes and its working. But, while I am trying to echo it it only echo the last row. However I would like to echo the row with the previous input. How can I do it. Do you have any suggesting for that

Answer (score 0):

Foreach walks arrays by itself

You don't need $a+1 nor the reference to [$a] in your code for that purpose

The following suggestion works fine if you use the same name for variables and POST inputs (which seems to be your case)

First define a safe() function in which you take care of possible sql injection attacks as mentionned in comments

And then

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $$key = safe($value);
}
```

will retrieve the values your looking for

Hope it helps !